# Why do I get "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" when deleting a pointer allocated with new?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

As stated, I'm getting "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" when **deleting a pointer allocated with new.** I've never seen this error before, and it occurs in `main`.

Main.ccp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "ConsolePrinter.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;

    ObjectPrinter* op1 = new ConsolePrinter('V');
    op1->printObject();

    delete op1;
}
```

`ConsolePrinter` is derived from `ObjectPrinter`. Both are custom classes

ObjectPrinter.h:

```
#ifndef OBJECTPRINTER_H
#define OBJECTPRINTER_H

#include <typeinfo>

class ObjectPrinter {
public:
    virtual bool compatible(const ObjectPrinter* objprtr) const = 0;
    virtual void printObject() = 0;
    virtual const std::type_info& getType() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

ConsolePrinter.h:

```
#ifndef CONSOLEPRINTER_H
#define CONSOLEPRINTER_H

#include "ObjectPrinter.h"

class ConsolePrinter : public virtual ObjectPrinter {
public:
    ConsolePrinter();
    ConsolePrinter(unsigned char c);

    bool compatible(const ObjectPrinter* objprtr) const;
    virtual void printObject();
protected:
    const bool compatibilityMode;

    virtual const std::type_info& getType() const;
private:
    const unsigned char repr;
};

#endif
```

Before `delete op1;`:

- The address of `op1` is `0x00E1BF7C`.
- Within the heap, `op1` is instance `<0x00E1BF50>` (according to Visual Studio's HEAP snapshot).

When `delete op1;` is executed, the error given is `Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00E10000, 00E1BF5C )`.

If someone can explain why this is happening, I would be very appreciated.

Comment: [No `virtual` destructor could be the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors). Hard to say for sure without a complete example.

Comment: That's just crazy enough to work. I'll get back to you once I'm back at my workstation and can test it.

Comment: Let us know if it is and we'll close as a duplicate. If it isn't we'll probably need more in the example code.

Comment: It worked. Should I put that as the answer then, or will marking as duplicate suffice?